# Convert List<String> to List<Object> or even List<Integer> by cast

Tags: java, list, generics

There is a question [How to Convert List<String> to List<Object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288084/how-to-convert-liststring-to-listobject) and many similar questions about `List<P>` and `List<C>` with C extends P.

Obviously, we cannot using cast like this:

```
List<String> list0 = Arrays.asList("abc", "xyz");
List<Object> list1 = (List<Object>) list0; //ERROR here
```

the accepted answer in above question is:

```
List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<Object>(stringList);
```

but when I try this code:

```
List<String> list0 = Arrays.asList("abc", "xyz");
List<Object> list1 = (List<Object>) (Object) list0;
System.out.println(list1);
```

Even like this:

```
List<String> list0 = Arrays.asList("abc", "xyz");
List<Integer> list1 = (List<Integer>) (Object) list0;
System.out.println(list1);
```

It runs successfully, so we can cast indirectly! I really doubt this! any acceptable reason for this?

Comment: @Logan not duplicated, I know it cannot cast, so I understand my question

Comment: @saka1029 or just `List<?>` which is the same thing only shorter :D

Comment: I don't talk about cast to which type, I talk about cast to exactly List<Object> without any error

Answer (score 2):

This is (more or less) to be expected. Java generics only exist in the compiler, not at runtime. The compiler checks whether everything works out, and then erases the types so only `Object` (or whatever lower bound) remains.

If you cast to `Object` along the way, you're no longer casting one generic type to another directly, and the compiler can't verify anything, so it's permitted. And since the generic types no longer exist at runtime it also works. But you may upset code using that list because you can now add `Object`s instead of just `String`s. That double-cast in the way you're doing it is likely fine when you're only enumerating the list, but if possible I'd avoid doing that in either case. Type safety is a nice thing.

With your cast to `List<Integer>` exactly the same thing is happening. The reason it still works is because you're just printing the list (not sure whether that enumerates and writes the list's contents in Java, but if it does, then it will likely call `toString()` on the elements anyway. Since `toString` is a method on `Object` there is no difference whether you call it on an `Integer` or a `String`. The resulting bytecode is the same. However if you called methods of `Integer` instead, then you'll definitely get a crash at runtime, even though the compiler, as noted before, can't save you from doing stupid things.

Comment: I have update my question when cast to List of Integer

Answer (score 2):

Writing:

```
List<Integer> list1 = (List<Integer>) (Object) list0;
```

is equivalent to:

```
Object obj = (Object) list0;
List<Integer> list1 = (List<Integer>) obj;
```

As far as the compiler is concerned, casting any reference type to `Object` is always valid (since all reference types are `Object`s). The second cast is also allowed, since as far as the compiler is concerned, the `Object` reference may hold (in run-time) a reference to any reference type, so it will allow you can cast to any type (even to `Set<Integer>`, which will pass compilation and only fail in run-time).

Now, at run-time, after generic type parameters are erased, your code becomes:

```
List list0 = Arrays.asList("abc", "xyz");
List list1 = (List) (Object) list0;
System.out.println(list1);
```

Both casts are valid in run-time, so your code doesn't cause a `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 1):

Casts from `Generic<Subclass>` to `Generic<SuperClass>` are unsafe, but most developers do not care about this. Look at following example classes

```
class Fruit {
}
class Apple extends Fruit {
}
```

Where an `Apple` always can be used as `Fruit` a `Bowl<Apple>` cannot be used as a `Bowl<Fruit>`. If I cast `Bowl<Apple>` to `Bowl<Fruit>`, I may later on add an `Orange` to the fruit bowl and the original apple bowl will contain an orange. Example:

```
Bowl<Apple> apples = new Bowl<Apple>();
...
Bowl<Fruit> fruit = (Bowl<Apple>) apples; // no exception
fruit.add(new Orange()); // no exception
...
Apple apple = apples.get(0); // no compiler warning, but exception
```

So the purpose of not allowing a cast is probably to remind the user that he is probably doing something that he does not understand.

Yet the compiler allows us to cast `Fruit` to `Apple`. This is a limitation of Java (other languages allow only safe casts (with type checks ensuring that the cast is possible)), but it is not that bad as generic casts, because the exception is thrown at the location where the illegal cast is done - while with generic casts the exception may occur even in another classes method.

Yet there are scenarios where we know that a fruit bowl will only contain apples (also in future) or a list will always contain Strings (e.g. if the data is not modifiable). In such scenarios, I would prefer the idiom:

```
List<Object> list1 = (List<Object>) (List) list0;
```

Answer (score 0):

List and List are incompatible. But you can write:

```
List<Object> list1 = (List<Object>)(List<?>)  list0;
```