# How do I convert from List<T> to List<String> in Java

Tags: java

In java I need to write a method which  convert a `list<T>` to `list<String>`, I try this:

```
private List<String> convertTlistToString(List<T> listOfT) {
        List<String> convertList = new ArrayList<>();

        if (listOfT != null) {
            for (T list : listOfT) {
                String t = list.toString();
                convertList.add(t);
            }
        }

        return convertList;
    }
```

thank for your help.

Comment: You need to explain what the `List<String>` should actually contain. What is the relationship between the input `T` and the output string? What have you tried? Where did it fail?

Comment: All Java objects have a `toString()` method.  So for your `List<String>`, just populate it with `t.toString()`. If you want the `List<String>` to contain more useful information, you'll need to either override the `toString()` method, or provide your own method of determine how `T` should be represented as a `String`

Comment: Can you share a bit of code?

Comment: `static <T> List<String> toStringList(List<T> al) {return al.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());}`

Comment: And what doesn't work with the code you just added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people mention in the comments, you can use Java .toString() method for each object on your `List<T>` and populate your `List<String>`.

You can also check out this and apply it to your case

[How to Convert List<String> to List<Object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288084/how-to-convert-liststring-to-listobject?answertab=active#tab-top)

You have many ways to solve it, I recommend you to post some code of your class and be more specific of what you wanna cast to String for populating your `List<String>`.

EDIT: The code you posted should work fine.

Answer (score -1):

You should try List.toString();
It will convert it to String

Comment: That will not return `List<String>`.